# Firebase loading $scope view enter doesn't load

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I have a loading problem in Firebase. I want to display a list of images when I open the view but nothing happens till i go back ( there is a flash and i can see my photo list). It's working but not displaying in the opening. 
What am i missing please ?

There is the beginning of my Controller view:

```
'Use Strict';
angular.module('App').controller('valider_photosController', function($scope, $state, $localStorage, Popup, Firebase, $firebaseObject, $ionicHistory, $ionicPopup, $ionicModal, $cordovaCamera) {

  $scope.imagestab = [];
  var ref_logements = firebase.database().ref('logements');
  var ref_images = firebase.database().ref('images');

  ref_logements.child(id_logement).child('images').on('child_added', added);

  function added(idxSnap, prevId){
      ref_images.child(idxSnap.key).once('value', function(datasnap){
          var bidule = datasnap.val();
          bidule['key'] = datasnap.key;
          $scope.imagestab.push(bidule);
          console.log('La valeur'+datasnap.key+'donne '+datasnap.val());
      });
  }; 

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since firebase works with asynchronous calls, by the time firebase responds with your data the angular cycle had already finished and you won't have your scope updated. You can force it by using `$scope.$apply();`.

```
ref_images.child(idxSnap.key).once('value', function(datasnap){
      var bidule = datasnap.val();
      bidule['key'] = datasnap.key;
      $scope.imagestab.push(bidule);
      $scope.$apply();
});
```

---

There is a tool that integrates angular and firebase in a way that you won't have to be concerned with things such as applying the scope. Its called [angularfire](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire). I totally recommend you to start using it in your application.

With angularfire you can get your data simply using

```
$scope.bidule = $firebaseObject(ref_images.child(idxSnap.key));
```

or

```
$scope.images = $firebaseArray(firebase.database().ref('images'));
```

Comment: You're right ! Angularfire is perfect for that thank you ... again :)

Answer (score 0):

I created a Factory

```
.factory('Firebase', function ($firebaseArray, $firebaseObject) {
        var ref = firebase.database().ref();
        return {
            all: function (section) {
                var data = $firebaseArray(ref.child(section));
                return data;
            },
            getById: function (section, id) {
                var data = $firebaseObject(ref.child(section).child(id));
                return data;
            },
            get: function (section, field, value) {
                var data = $firebaseArray(ref.child(section).orderByChild(field).equalTo(value));
                return data;
            }
      };
  })
```

And then in my controller, i replaced like you said :

```
        var ref_logements = firebase.database().ref('logements');
        var ref_images = firebase.database().ref('images');
        ref_logements.child(index2).child('images').on('child_added', added);

        function added(idxSnap, prevId) {
            var monimage = Firebase.getById('images', idxSnap.key);
            $scope.imagestab.push(monimage);
        };
```

And it Works like a charm ! Thank you again :)

Comment: Whaouu, I really want to thank you @adolfosrs because i changed all the references in my app with angularFire and it's really fast and clean now.